# Move network interface to "Domain network"

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2

Is it possible to move all network interfaces to "Domain Network" on Windows Server 2008R2?

In default after installation I have one in Domain and next two in Public Network and I want to have them all only in Domain Network

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

1. Get the index number of the network interface you want to change:

   ```
   Get-NetConnectionProfile
   ```
2. Change it to `DomainAuthenticated`

   ```
   Set-NetConnectionProfile -InterfaceIndex <InterfaceIndex number> -NetworkCategory DomainAuthenticated
   ```

Comment: Those cmdlets do not exist on Server 2008.  I believe they were introduced in 2012R2.